# Mysql, order by "pattern"?

Tags: mysql

I want to order by type, by a pattern. Records now:

type name

```
1    a
2    b
1    c
4    d
4    e
3    f
2    g
3    h
```

my pattern is `2,4,3,1` so I would like to get:

```
2    b
2    g
4    d
4    e
3    f
3    h
1    a
1    c
```

Comment: try .. `order by field (type,2,4,3,1)`

Comment: what is this name? How is it called? Order by pattern?

Comment: Sorry did not get you. field is a string function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19867118/symfony2-createquery-order-by-field  nevermind. Post your answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `order by field (type,2,4,3,1)`. This will give you the correct result.